# Working CSS positioning not depending on screen size

Tags: html, css, browser, position

Ive had quite some problems with positioning elements with CSS related to people using differently sized screens. Whats a bulletproof way to position elements so that they keep their position on the screen no matter how big the viewport is?

Comment: Use fixed width, eg pixels instead %.

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do, but it still doesnt make complete sense to me.. Say I got a screen with a viewport of 1366px x 636 px, like I do right now, and another screen with a viewport of 800px x 600px. If I position an element 100px to the right, it will not appear in the same position on both of the screens, will it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have got 2 simple examples here.

In demo 1, div will always stick to top left of the screen regardless of screen size/resolution.

[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/HGdcN/1/)

```
<div id="test">This div will always appear on top left by default regardless of screen size.</div>​
#test{ width:150px; height:150px; background-color:#666; }​
```

This one will always stick to right hand side with some margin

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/HGdcN/3/)

```
<div id="test">This div will always appear on right hand with 100 margin.</div>​
#test{float:right; margin-right:100px; width:150px; height:150px; background-color:#666; }​
```

Answer (score 0):

wraped div. For example:

html:

```
<div class="wraped">
  <div class="someDiv">
      Hi
  </div>
  <div class="someDiv">
    Hi reloaded
  </div>
</div>​
```

css:

```
​.wraped {
  background:grey;
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  margin:auto                
 }
 .someDiv  {
   width:230px;
   text-align:center;
   padding:10px;
   background:#ccc;
   outline:1px solid black;
   float:left;
  }
```

You can preview this in http://jsfiddle.net/wandarkaf/2VVcm/
​